# What is the difference between rcuc and rcub

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, kernel

What is the difference between rcuc and rcub Kernal threads?

I know that rcu (Read-Copy_Update) is a synchronization mechanism that manages reads and updates simultaneously.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update

And I understand that there are thress main usages for the mechanism:

> a.    rcu_read_lock() / rcu_read_unlock()     rcu_dereference()
>
> b.    rcu_read_lock_bh() / rcu_read_unlock_bh()   local_bh_disable() /
> local_bh_enable()     rcu_dereference_bh()
>
> c.    rcu_read_lock_sched() / rcu_read_unlock_sched()     preempt_disable()
> / preempt_enable()    local_irq_save() / local_irq_restore()  hardirq
> enter / hardirq exit  NMI enter / NMI exit    rcu_dereference_sched()

According to :
[Blockquotehttps://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt](http://Blockquotehttps://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt)

Yet I didn't find information about rcu{c,b} & when each of these is used, and what "c" and "b" stands for?

Answer (score 3):

ok , found it :

> Rename CONFIG_RCU_BOOST_PRIO to CONFIG_RCU_KTHREAD_PRIO and use this
> value for both **the per-CPU kthreads (rcuc/N) and the rcu boosting
> threads (rcub/n).**

http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1409.2/00514.html